# paramiko on windows - does it use cygwin or cmd?

Tags: windows, command, cygwin, command-line-interface, paramiko

I know for paramiko's ssh connection to work, i need cygwin installed on a Windows. Objective is to run commands remotely from a Linux to a Windows server and then process the output again on Linux server or on Windows itself.

I am confused because, "ipconfig" sent from Linux to Windows using "ssh_obj.exec_command("ipconfig")" works but not "ssh_obj.exec_command("dir")" - tried giving the path like "cd C:\Users\Administrator" for cmd or "cd C:" followed by "cd  Users/Administrator" like in Cygwin. Neither of them work.

So what does paramiko use when I use Windows to send across commands remotely? Does anyone know?

Comment: paramiko sends a `MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST` for an `"exec"`. How it executes is up to the server. Probably Cygwin's sshd daemon forks a new process and execs `/bin/sh -c command`. It wouldn't use cmd.exe. `ipconfig` succeeds because it's not a cmd shell internal command, but ipconfig.exe. If you want to interact with the shell, then call [`invoke_shell`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.invoke_shell) instead. That sends a `"shell"` request.

Comment: But invoke_shell also returns only an object after opening a channel just like exec_command does. I want the output of "dir" to be given to me

Comment: After invoking a shell you can `send` commands and `recv` the output. `dir` won't work in a POSIX shell; use `send('ls\n')`. I suppose you could run `cmd`, but I don't know why you'd want that.

Comment: I am not sure how you want me to try this. Could you give me an example with 2 lines of code -- leveraging what I have at the top in the first post? Thanks~

Comment: `ssh = paramiko.SSHClient(); ssh.connect(hostname, username, password);` `chan = ssh.invoke_shell();` `chan.send('ls\n');` `while not chan.recv_ready(): pass;` `output = chan.recv(10000)`.

Comment: 'code' channel = ssh_obj.invoke_shell() stdout = channel.send("ls\n") while not channel.recv_ready(): pass output = channel.recv(10000). When I print output, I get "Last login: Sun May 32 14:43:56 2015 from xxx.xx.xx.xxx " (IP).. That's not the output i was hoping to see. I wanted to see a list of files...

Comment: OK, there was a login message that you'd have to skip past. Done like this you're actually driving an interactive shell session. The alternative is executing an individual command via `exec_command`, which could be a shell script; in that case the channel is closed after running the command.

Comment: Well - that's what I had posted in my first post - "ls" or "dir" using "exec_command" gives me no response!

Comment: You didn't say you tried `ls`, which is why in my first comment I said Cygwin's `sshd` daemon wouldn't use cmd.exe (and thus the cmd shell's internal `dir` command would not work). `ls` should work. It returns a 3-tuple `(stdin, stdout, stderr)` of file-like objects, and you should be able to use `stdout.read()` or `stdout.readlines()`.

Comment: Yes, after you had suggested "ls", I did try it out but neither stdout.read() nor stdout.readlines() works. The former comes out empty and the latter comes with "[]
"

Comment: printing sterrr.read() and stderr.readlines() gives empty and "[]", respectively

Comment: eryksun - I was making a mistake - called "ifconfig" with "exec_command" just before calling "ls" with "exec_command" .. it looks like i have to put a sleep call between the commands. When I commented out the "ifconfig" stuff, "ls" started workign.. something to do with buffers, may be?

Answer (score 0):

**In your words, Cygwin**

According to @eryksun:

> Paramiko sends a `MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST` for an `"exec"`. How it executes is up to the server. Probably Cygwin's sshd daemon forks a new process and execs `/bin/sh -c command`. It wouldn't use cmd.exe. ipconfig succeeds because it's not a cmd shell internal command, but [an application,] ipconfig.exe. If you want to interact with the shell, then call invoke_shell instead. That sends a "shell" request.

As for why two exec_command() calls don't work right in a row, @eryksun also mentioned this. exec_command() closes the channel it is using. If you want to make more than one call, you'll need to recreate the channel or client. I usually just do the channel. Here's the code I recommend for such interactions:

```
def run_cmd(sshClient, command):
    channel = sshClient.get_transport().open_session()
    channel.get_pty()
    channel.exec_command(command)
    out = channel.makefile().read()
    err = channel.makefile_stderr().read()
    returncode = channel.recv_exit_status()
    channel.close()                       # channel is closed, but not the client
    return out, err, returncode

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname, username = user, password = pw)
out, err, rc = run_cmd(client, "ifconfig")
# Do whatever with the output
out, err, rc = run_cmd(client, "ls")
# Do whatever with the output
```